# How to order slice of pointers using gqlgen and dataloaden (graphql dataloader) if some keys are NULL?

Tags: arrays, go, data-structures, dataloader, gqlgen

I have these entities:

- Golang struct:

```golang
type Player struct {
    ID        int
    CreatedAt time.Time
    City      City
    CityID    int
    Team      *Team
    TeamID    *int
    Score     int
}
```

- GraphQL schema:

```
type Player {
  id: ID!
  createdAt: Time!
  City: City!
  Team: Team
  Score: Int!
}
```

As you can see:

1. `City` is mandatory
2. `Team` (and `TeamID` in Golang struct) is NOT mandatory, so I'm using a pointer type (`*`)

What I don't understand now is how to use `dataloaden` (a GraphQL dataloader).

Here the generated code for `CityById` loader, generated with: `go run github.com/vektah/dataloaden CityByIdLoader int *my_project/entities.City`:

```golang
CityById: CityByIdLoader{
  maxBatch: 100,
  wait:     1 * time.Millisecond,
  fetch: func(keys []int) ([]*entities.City, []error) {
    cities, err := myRepo.CitiesByKeys(keys)
    // directly ordered in DB based on keys` order: it works
    return cities, []error{err}
  },
},
```

What about `[]*int` for `TeamID`?

Here's the generated code for `TeamById` loader, generated with: `go run github.com/vektah/dataloaden TeamByIdLoader *int *my_project/entities.Team`:

```golang
TeamById: TeamByIdLoader{
  maxBatch: 100,
  wait:     1 * time.Millisecond,
  fetch: func(keys []int) ([]*entities.Team, []error) {
    teams, err := myRepo.TeamsByKeys(keys)
    // I cannot order in DB because of `NULL` keys, right?
    // How to order these results?
    return teams, []error{err}
  },
},
```

**I don't understand how to re-order teams by keys if I cannot do it in DB because of `NULL` values in `keys`.**